# Sharepoint flow list access issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow, site

I am trying to create a flow for sharepoint. I chose when a new item is created trigger. When I open the site address drop down, it shows 'No items' and 'Enter a custom value'. Even if I try using enter a custom value, I cannot find my lists in the List Name dropdown though few other lists are present. If I choose one of these lists, I still cannot get the dynamic content for them.

Can anyone tell me why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

In the List Name section, type your list name manually and check if the it’s available under Microsoft Flow.

If the issue exists, click on the gear in the top-right corner of the Flow page, click on Connections, make sure the SharePoint connection status is connected.